# Printing php function using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to print text using jquery, but inside this text I have a php function.
The problem is: It is printing the function commented and i dont know why

```
$('.addsupplier').click(function() {
    $('.blockthirdpartyservicesupplier:last').after('<div class="blockthirdpartyservicesupplier" id="blockthirdpartyservicesupplier"><div class="widget-content nopadding"><div class="control-group hidden"><div class="controls"><label><div class="radio" id="uniform-undefined"><span class=""><input type="radio" name="thirdpartyservicesupplierid[]" class="thirdpartyservicesupplierid" value="blank" checked="checked"/></span></div></label></div></div><div class="control-group"><label class="control-label">Fornecedor</label><div class="controls"><?php GetSuppliersSelect(); ?> <span class="removesupplier btn btn-danger"> Excluir </span></div></div><div class="control-group"><label class="control-label">Preço</label><div class="controls"><div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on">R$</span><input type="text" maxlength="10" name="thirdpartyservicesupplierprice[]" class="thirdpartyservicesupplierprice price"></div></div></div></div></div>');
});
```

It is printing everything ok but the php function are being printed like this:

```
<!--?php GetSuppliersSelect(); ?-->
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between client side and server side scripting?

Comment: Is that page a php script or plain html?

Comment: Confirm that your code file (webpage) has extension of `.php` and not `.html` and you will be good to go then.

Comment: its .php coded idk why dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is not being executed, because it's already on the client side among all the javascript. In this scenario you would need an ajax request, or pre-generate the supplier list into the javascript code.

The latter option would look like this: a PHP script that would "echo" the supplier list ready to be inserted into javascript string. Lots of sanitization, backslashes and generally confusing, less flexible, not recommended.

Better approach is with ajax: PHP script that will output only the suppliers as a JSON array. Then in this javascript code before calling the `$('.blockthirdpartyservicesupplier:last').after(` you would call the ajax request, pointing to your json php script. After receiving the response, you would cycle through the json array, form the needed html tags to create the `<select>`s, and append using jQuery.